# ¿Es posible añadir "required" con jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formularios

Estoy validando un formulario con jQuery, aun que dando algo de vueltas al asunto, he pensado, si sería posible, añadir a través de jQuery, según el usuario va escogiendo unas opciones u otras, añadir el atributo required a los campos necesarios.

He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente forma, y no me ha funcionado:

```
  $('#detalles').on('change', function(){
    var id_tipo = $('#detalles').val()

      if (id_tipo==1) {
        $("familiaOI").prop('required');
        $("familiaOD").prop('required'); ....
```

También con .attr().., y no me ha funcionado.

- Después, ¿sería posible desde un input (type="button").. darle click, y que compruebe si los campos con required están rellenos?
- Si estan llenos, ej: muestra un alert con "OK", si no estan rellenos, marcar los campos con borde rojo (addClass()...)
- He probado de hacerlo en varias formas, pero no consigo que funcione bien, con lo que por eso pido ayuda.

**ESTOY PROBANDO A VALIDAD DE LA SIGUIENTE FORMA:**

```
$("#comprobarDatos").on("click", function(){

  var id_tipo = $('#detalles').val()
  // SI ELIGEN MISMO / DIFERENTE MATERIAL, COMPRUEBA QUE:
  if (id_tipo == 1) {

    if($('#familiaOD').val() == "") {
      $('#familiaOD').addClass("ok");
      $("#familiaOD").on("click", function(){
        $('#familiaOD').removeClass("ok");
      });
    } else if($('#familiaOD').val() == "1") {

      if($('#disenyoOD').val() == "") {
          $('#disenyoOD').addClass("ok");
          $("#disenyoOD").on("click", function(){
          $('#disenyoOD').removeClass("ok");
        });
      } else if($('#indiceOD').val() == "") {
          $('#indiceOD').addClass("ok");
          $("#indiceOD").on("click", function(){
          $('#indiceOD').removeClass("ok");
        });
      } else if($('#materialOD').val() == "") {
          $('#materialOD').addClass("ok");
          $("#materialOD").on("click", function(){
          $('#materialOD').removeClass("ok");
        });
      } else if($('#TratamientoOD').val() == "") {
          $('#TratamientoOD').addClass("ok");
          $("#TratamientoOD").on("click", function(){
          $('#TratamientoOD').removeClass("ok");
        });
      } else if($('#CylOD').val() == "") {
          $('#CylOD').addClass("ok");
          $("#CylOD").on("click", function(){
          $('#CylOD').removeClass("ok");
        });
      } else if($('#SphOD').val() == "") {
          $('#SphOD').addClass("ok");
          $("#SphOD").on("click", function(){
          $('#SphOD').removeClass("ok"); . . . . .
```

Se supone que en el "else" final, mando un "modal" con un comprobar datos, muestra un resumen, y ya me dejaría enviar el formulario.

El problema, que de esta forma, lo veo un poco "mal" algunas condiciones no puedo agregarlas bien, este formulario tiene más de 100 campos con muchísimas condiciones, por eso intento simplemente añadir required, y al darle a comprobar datos, si los "required" estan rellenados, que muestre el modal, si no, marcarlos en rojo.

**EL HTML:**

```
        <select id="familiaOD" name="familiaOD">
        </select>

        <select id="familiaOI" name="familiaOI">
        </select>
```

Gracias a todos de ante mano.

Comment: Solo te falto agregar los selectores (# .) por ejemplo: **$("familiaOI").prop('required');** no hará nada porque no encuentra el nodo pero si fuera **$("#familiaOI").prop('required');** ahí si funcionaria.

Comment: Vaya despiste, madremia, para darme con un palo jejejeje, así si funciona, y el resto de la question, como podría buscar una solución

Comment: si eso tambien vale que bueno que el pana se dio cuenta hasta ami se me estaba pasando XD

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resto que no te funciona? XD

Comment: Okey, a ver, ahora, tengo un input de type button, al que al darle click, necesito que me compruebe si todos los requiere están seleccionados, si no es así, marcarlos con borde rojo, sin embargo, si los han rellenado correctamente, mostrar por ejemplo un alert que diga "ok"

Comment: ¿Haz pensado en usar algún plugin? podrías usar [Validation.js](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)  y solo configurar los campos, proporcionan buena interfaz de mensajes de respuestas, a ver por ahora te pondré una respuesta con algo según lo que planteas.

Comment: Voy a mirarme el plugin, espero tu respuesta muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Debes poner el campo de `required` en `true`. Algo asi te deberia funccionar:

```
$("input").prop('required', true);
//ó
$("input").attr("required", true);
```

```js
$('#validar').click(function(){
    
   
   if($('select[required]').val()==""){
      
       alert("select requiere no choosed")
    }else{
    
    alert("thank you for choosing")
     }


});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="frm">
   <select multiple name="sel" id="sel" required>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
    <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
    <option value="5">Cinco</option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" name="btn" value="Enviar" id="validar">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He editado mi pregunta, porque me pareció que habías puesto un comentario, de todos modos, estoy probando con eso, y al seleccionar la opción con value="1", el atributo "required" no lo añade al select

Comment: Es decir, cuando (id_tipo==1) las acciones que hay si las realiza, menos añadir required

Comment: pon tu codigo html tambien

Comment: Listo, ya está añadido, aun que son 2 simples select vacíos, ya que lo relleno con php a través de ajax

Comment: en estos casos es bueno poner todo el codigo para detectar la raiz del problema, no entiendo muy bien cuales input quieres ponerle un requiere si lo que tienes son dos select?

Comment: No quiero poner los requiere a ningún input, los quiero añadir a los "select", todo el formulario son select.

Comment: Disculpa si la pregunta ha podido confundir

Comment: vamos por paso por que la verdad que esta un poco confusa tu logica, que es lo que intentas hacer en realidad que esperas que haga tu codigo una ves has seleccionado un select , esta el select dentro de un formulario?

Comment: A ver, el formulario tiene más de 100 campos, todos son "select", lo de los required, ya lo tengo solucionado, ahora, desde un botón, al darle click, necesito comprobar que todos los required están rellenos y no vacíos, en caso de que estén completos, mandar un "ok", si algiuno falta por rellenar, lo quiero marcar en rojo con un addClass

Comment: y lograste hacerlo ? osea se ponen en rojo ?

Comment: Sí, con el código que tengo ahora sí, pero no me sirve, porque lo que quiero comprobar es que TODOS los campos con required, estén rellenos y no vacíos.

Comment: mira un pequeno ejemplo que te puse en un sniper de como seria mas o menos

Comment: Ahí verificamos que el select esté vacío, pero necesito validar que los select con required están seleccionados

Comment: ya te lo arregle checa ahora la edicion si es lo que buscas

Answer (score 1):

Para el primer caso sólo te faltó agregar los selectores (# .) por ejemplo: `$("familiaOI").prop('required');` no hará nada porque no encuentra el nodo pero si fuera `$("#familiaOI").prop('required');` ahí si funcionaria. Y para lo otro que propones como te comenté, sería bueno que pruebes con algún plugin para que te quede mejor sin tanto esfuerzo, por mientras te pongo una posible solución, espero te sirva.

```
    $("#btnSubmit").submit(function( event ) {
    var $campo = $("#txtValorAcomprobar").Text();
    if($campo == "")
    {   // a decir verdad esto el navegador ya lo hace por defecto,
        // con un mensaje debajo de la caja de texto, pero bueno es mas personalizado
        alert("debe rellenar el campo");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```